# Markdown Nested Lists with Multiple Lines under Single Bullet

Tags: list, markdown

Is it possible to create markdown lists so that I can have multiple lines under a single bullet as in the example below:

[image: Nested List with Multiple Lines under Single Bullet]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the markdown flavour and the markdown processor used.

Using `<br>` should often work.

It does here on Stack Exchange. This list:

- First bullet
  new line

  - Sublist
    ...with a new line
- Second bullet

...is generated with:

```
* First bullet<br>new line
  * Sublist<br>...with a new line
* Second bullet
```

Comment: Thanks! <br> is the solution.